# Why do Apple's SimplePing pings succeed on an iphone in AIRPLANE MODE?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, connection

I'm pinging "google.com" using Apple's SimplePing example: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html

The pings succeed also when I set the iphone to Airplane Mode.

note: pinging this didn't work also:

```
"google.com?random=" + a random int;
```

**Why do the pings succeed?**

Comment: You can't ping an URL. You can only ping machines and their interfaces.

Comment: Can I ping a machine and its interface using a URL? In my mac terminal i'm writing "ping google.com" and it works. no?

Comment: `google.gom` is not an URL in this context. It's just a domain name, which is but a part of an URL.